# mode-line, Status :: Added to Agenda

Tags: org-agenda, mode-line

I'd like some kind of visual feedback in the mode-line, saying whether the current buffer is a file that is added to the org-agenda. Is there some way to do that?;)

Comment: Do you just mean "is a member of `org-agenda-files`" ?

Comment: @phils Yes, cause I find myself adding TODOs' all over the place and I'm constantly not sure if the file I add the TODO to, is part of the agenda, so that the TODO will be visible when I run org-agenda views

Comment: Are the files necessarily *.org files?

Answer (score 1):

I recommend always avoiding unnecessary dynamic evaluations in the mode line, so I suggest you do the look-up in `find-file-hook`.  The simplest approach to that means that you won't *automatically* see mode line 'corrections' to existing buffers if you update `org-agenda-files` (you would need to revisit the file), but the benefit is that the mode line rendering is very cheap.

```el
(require 'org)

(defvar-local my-org-agenda-file-p nil
  "Whether this buffer's file is a member of `org-agenda-files'.")

(defun my-org-agenda-file-check ()
  "Update `my-org-agenda-file-p'."
  (when (member buffer-file-name (org-agenda-files t))
    (setq my-org-agenda-file-p t)))

(add-hook 'find-file-hook #'my-org-agenda-file-check)

(add-to-list 'global-mode-string '(my-org-agenda-file-p "Agenda"))
```

I can't guess whether you want to pass the ARCHIVES argument to `org-agenda-files`, so you should check that yourself.

```
(org-agenda-files &optional UNRESTRICTED ARCHIVES)
```

Comment: Instead of the `(mapcar #'expand-file-name org-agenda-files)`, it might be better to use `(org-agenda-files)` which expands the variable appropriately in all cases.

Comment: Much better; thanks NickD.